# Converter Json em Array com Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estou fazendo uma requisição ajax com jquery e Php assim:

```
// arquivo php
    $json = array(
      "status"=>"true",
      "message"=>"inserido com sucesso"
    );

    echo json_encode($json);
```

.

```
// arquivo js
    $.ajax({
        url, url,
        type: "post",
        data: dados,
        success: function(json){
          console.log(json);
        },
        error: function(){
          msg.text("Erro ao fazer requisição");
        }
      });
```

O meu `console.log` devolve `{"status":"true","message":"inserido com sucesso"}` e queria fosse transformado em um array Java Script, como eu poderia fazer essa conversão ?

Comment: Basta adicionar o atributo `dataType: "json"` à sua requisição AJAX.

Comment: funcionou obrigado, acha melhor eu fechar a pergunta ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o `$.map`, assim transformara o json em array.

```
// arquivo js
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "post",
    data: dados,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json){
      let arr = $.map(json, function(el) { return el; })
      console.log(arr['status']);
      console.log(arr['message']);
    },
    error: function(){
      msg.text("Erro ao fazer requisição");
    }
});
```

Caso queira somente fazer o json do PHP ser um objeto/json no javascript, basta adicionar `dataType: 'json'`

```
// arquivo js
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "post",
    data: dados,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json){
      console.log(json.status);
      console.log(json.message);
    },
    error: function(){
      msg.text("Erro ao fazer requisição");
    }
});
```